# Checkbox in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, win-universal-app

I have a `<Checkbox/>` in my `<GridView.ItemTemplate>`. How do I handle the `<Checkbox/>` as to the element in which it is?

**For example**, I want to delete item when checkbox checked.

I think should write here. But what?

```
private void CheckBox_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Here's My XAML:

```
<GridView Margin="0,10,0,0" 
        RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
        x:Name="GridColections"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        SelectionMode="None"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind DS.AllRem, Mode=OneWay}"
        ItemClick="GridColections_ItemClick" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:GetRem" >
            <Grid Margin="-2,0,-6,0" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{x:Bind ReminderName}" Margin="5,5,0,0" FontSize="20"/>
                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="600" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{x:Bind ReminderDescription}" Margin="5,5,0,0" FontSize="12"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Try var item= (sender as Check Box).DataContext  as your class. You will get the item which is checked

Comment: @LovetoCode It's works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you almost certainly want to be able to use the `DataContext` in your click handler but you won't get that easily by just having a reference to the `CheckBox` which will be the sender argument in your callback. Normally what you would do here is create a `Command` on your item's view model and bind to that and any additional information that you would want to pass in you would pass in through the `CheckBox`'s `CommandParameter`.

Once you do this you are now operating in your view model with a reference to whatever piece of information that you need through the command parameter (for instance you could set `CommandParameter = "{Binding}"` to pick up the entire data context which would be the item's view model and that would be accessible from your `Command` as an argument to it). You should be able to solve your issue this way.